# How can I get the lenth of a session in django views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using a code for my wish list . I need the no of products in the wishlist to show there on my site .I tried various methods but I Think session will only do this .Can some help please .

How can I do so .

```
@never_cache
def wishlist(request, template="shop/wishlist.html"):
    """
    Display the wishlist and handle removing items from the wishlist and
    adding them to the cart.
    """

    skus = request.wishlist
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        to_cart = request.POST.get("add_cart")
        add_product_form = AddProductForm(request.POST or None,
                                          to_cart=to_cart,request=request)
        if to_cart:
            if add_product_form.is_valid():
                request.cart.add_item(add_product_form.variation, 1,request)
                recalculate_discount(request)
                message = _("Item added to cart")
                url = "shop_cart"
            else:
                error = add_product_form.errors.values()[0]
        else:
            message = _("Item removed from wishlist")
            url = "shop_wishlist"
        sku = request.POST.get("sku")
        if sku in skus:
            skus.remove(sku)
        if not error:
            info(request, message)
            response = redirect(url)
            set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
            return response

    # Remove skus from the cookie that no longer exist.
    published_products = Product.objects.published(for_user=request.user)
    f = {"product__in": published_products, "sku__in": skus}
    wishlist = ProductVariation.objects.filter(**f).select_related(depth=1)
    wishlist = sorted(wishlist, key=lambda v: skus.index(v.sku))
    context = {"wishlist_items": wishlist, "error": error}
    response = render(request, template, context)
    if len(wishlist) < len(skus):
        skus = [variation.sku for variation in wishlist]
        set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
    return response
```

Comment: this funtion is used to add anf remove the products in my wishlist .

Comment: I need the number of products in the session .

Comment: What session? You are using cookies, not the session it seems?

Comment: yes cookies sesion it is .. would appritiate if you can help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session != Cookies. The session is managed by the server on the backend, cookies are sent to the users browser. [Django uses a single cookie to help track sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) but you are simply using cookies in this instance.

> The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID – not the data itself (unless you’re using the cookie based backend).

It's difficult to tell what you want, but if you simply want to get a count of the number of items you are saving in the cookie, you simply have to count your `sku`s and put it in the context being sent to the template:

```
if len(wishlist) < len(skus):
    skus = [variation.sku for variation in wishlist]
    set_cookie(response, "wishlist", ",".join(skus))
context = {"wishlist_items": wishlist, "error": error, "wishlist_length":len(wishlist)}
return render(request, template, context)
```

and use:

```
{{ wishlist_length }}
```

in your template